# Stream output data from Stream Analytics Job to Azure Synapse Analytics sql pool table?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-synapse

I have created a Stream Analytics Job and able to write the output data to a blob.
Now I want to write the output data in Azure Synapse Analytics SQL pool table.
I am getting below error while defining OUTPUT in Stream Analytics Job:

```
"SQL DW output needs job storage account to run. Please check if a job storage account has been configured for the job."
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/azure-synapse-analytics-output) (but not highlighted enough, I agree):

> To use Azure Synapse as output, **you need to ensure that you have the storage account configured**. Navigate to Storage account settings to configure the storage account.

This needs to be done at the **job level**, in the Azure Portal under **Configure** > **Storage account settings**.

[image]

Comment: Made the comment more visible in the doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/azure-synapse-analytics-output